# What does the below query explain?

Tags: php, mysql

What does the below query explain?

```
SELECT * FROM `jos_menu` WHERE (id = 69 OR id = 72)
```

I know its very silly question, but sometimes easy things creates mess in my skulls interpreter.. Pls help

> **EDIT**

Its giving me record for both IDs, why is it doing so? It should five me the record for either 69 or 72....

Comment: What exactly do you want the query to do? It is doing exactly as you asked. Silly computers!

Comment: `It should five me the record for either 69 or 72` -- SQL is not a procedural `if ... else` language, it's a **filter** language. It returns all records that match the filter expression.

Comment: I have a code I am browsing someone else code, And i found this query, so was wandering why is it doing so, I have weak hand in DB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean "Explain what the below query does", which I'll do:

- Return data from all of the columns in the `jos_menu` table. Return all rows whose id's are 69. Also return all rows whose id's are 72.

Essentially what it does is it goes through each row and checks:

1. Does this row have an id of either 69 or 72? If yes to either one, add it to the list of items returned.
2. Does this row have an id of either 69 or 72? If yes to either one, add it to the list of items returned.
3. Does this row have an id of either 69 or 72? If yes to either one, add it to the list of items returned.

etc..

Comment: Absolutely the same explanation i was looking for, Thanks @incrediman, U r incredible in reading my mind.... Thanx Mate

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT *
```

Get the values of every column

```
FROM `jos_menu`
```

From a table called "jos_menu"

```
WHERE (id = 69 OR id = 72)
```

And only fetch records that have an ID of 69 or 72

Edit:
In response to your edit ("Its giving me record for both IDs, why is doing so?"), you might want to try using the LIMIT keyword in your Sql. This will only grab the first match and then stop. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `jos_menu` WHERE (id = 69 OR id = 72) Limit 1
```

Comment: (+1) Although note that if you have both a 69 and a 72, the behaviour of that query is fairly undefined unless you add an `ORDER BY` - for example: `SELECT * FROM \`jos_menu\` ORDER BY id ASC WHERE (id = 69 OR id = 72) Limit 1`. Of course the behaviour is still pretty undefined if there can be multiple rows with the same id's, in which case you might want to `ORDER BY` something else as well.

Comment: Yep, thats a good point. I generally assume my ID's are in numeric order in the table (since they're auto_increment'd anyway) but its best to add the ORDER BY just in case.

Comment: I was actually not going by the assumption that the id was necessarily the primary key. Now that I think about it though, it likely is. And in that case my last sentence about duplicate id's also is not applicable :)

Comment: But still it's a good point. Though this might not be an issue in this case you should always take into account what kind of indeterministic behaviour you "allow".

Answer (score 1):

It will ask TABLE jos_menu for all the records that have an ID of 69 or 72.

Comment: Sorry its not doing this... budddy u r wrong... its giving me records for both

Comment: Yeah, it will select where the record is either 69 or 72, thus records for both.

Comment: That's correct. It will give you both records because it's not an exclusive 'or'. i.e. it doesn't stop processing the moment it finds a record. You will have to look into a different technique if you just want one record with either of those ids.

Comment: There's a number of techniques you can employ, mostly sql dialect specific. One is to use the limit parameter to specify just to return one record. Another is to use the first aggregate function. You need to look at what options your sql engine is offering. Alternatively you can bring both records back to the code and just use one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the columns from the table called `jos_menu` where the id column is equal to 69 or 72.

Comment: Don't you mean get all rows ? ;)

Comment: @Shadow: No, actually I didn't. I was translating SELECT *. Why people continually use * is beyond me. That's an anti pattern that needs to go...

Comment: Sorry while it selects all columns '*' it returns all rows.

Answer (score 0):

It lists all the rows from the table `jos_menu` where the column named `id` has value `69` or `72`

So effectively you'll get rows for both `id`'s

Answer (score 0):

Select all records from jos_menu where ID is *either* 69 or 72.

Answer (score 0):

The Query will return the records from the jos_menu table which satisfy the condtion  that id column that is exisiting in jos_menu  table having the id's as either 69 or 72.

A bettter way of writing it is

```
SELECT * FROM jos_menu WHERE id in ( 69 ,72)
```

here in the above query u can add any number of id's u want..

to limit to only one record

```
SELECT Top 1 * FROM jos_menu WHERE id in ( 69 ,72)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read it out loud remembering what the wildcards mean.

I'd read this as:

"Select all records from the table 'jos_menu' where the 'id' attribute is equal to 69 or 72"